# URLSearchParams is throwing empty object

Tags: reactjs, parameters

I'm facing a strange thing today. I used to use `URLSearchParams()` to extract the search params out of the URL. However, today, in my React app, it stopped working altogether when I used it as follows. Why `params` is an empty object here? any helpful advise is highly appreciated.

```js
// url of the web page is **http://localhost:3000/reset-password/?token=sks-4e5r-sklks-io**

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(window.location.search) // output -> ?token=sks-4e5r-sklks-io
    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    console.log(params) // output -> {}
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it also didn't solve my problem. It's strange because I have used this in past projects well..Anyway, I 'll try one more time and let u know the result.

Answer (score 1):

Use `new URL()` to enable `search`

Use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) with `get()` to get params

```
const url = new URL(window.location);
const params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
params.get("token")
```

You can try it via this sample:

```js
const App = () => {
  const url = new URL(
    "http://localhost:3000/reset-password/?token=sks-4e5r-sklks-io"
  );
  // const url = new URL(window.location);
  const params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
  console.log(params.get("token"));
  return <div className="App"></div>
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```